# ::before pseudo-element does not show

Tags: html, css, animation, flexbox, pseudo-element

in my snippet of code one .eye::before element shows but the other does not. I have not tried anything, because, frankly, I have no idea why. This is very new to me.

HTML:

```
<div class="face">
<div class="eyes">
  <div class="eye"></div>
  <div class="eye"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: here is the snippet: https://codepen.io/o1g/pen/WNbZyrv

Comment: position:relative on `.eye`